# Sortable Columns In scala.swing.Table

Tags: scala, swing

Consider this example code:

```
import swing._
import Swing._
import javax.swing.JTable
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel


class MyTable(columnNames: Seq[String], model: Seq[Seq[Any]]) extends Component {
  override lazy val peer = new JTable(new AbstractTableModel {
    def getValueAt(row: Int, col: Int): AnyRef = model(row)(col).asInstanceOf[AnyRef]
    def getColumnCount() = columnNames.length
    def getRowCount() = model.length
    override def isCellEditable(row: Int, column: Int) = false
  })
  peer setAutoCreateRowSorter true
}


object SO extends SimpleSwingApplication {

  implicit def tabelRowData2Array[T](rowData: Seq[Seq[T]]) = rowData.map(_.toArray[Any]).toArray

  val rowData     = Seq(Seq("1"), Seq("2"), Seq("3"))
  val columnNames = Seq("Nr")

  def top = new MainFrame {
    title = "TableTest"
    val scalaTable = new Table(rowData,columnNames) {
      peer setAutoCreateRowSorter true
    }
    val myTable = new MyTable(columnNames,rowData)
    contents = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Horizontal) {
      contents += new ScrollPane(scalaTable)
      contents += new ScrollPane(myTable)
    }
  }

}
```

Why are the columns in `scalaTable` not sortable when clicking on the column name while the columns in `myTable` are?
And how can I use `scala.swing.Table` with sortable columns instead of reimplementing it by `MyTable`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using TableRowSorter with scala.swing.Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588765/using-tablerowsorter-with-scala-swing-table)

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to my own question at [Using TableRowSorter with scala.swing.Table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9588765/1252732).  The Java 6 table sorting feature isn't implemented in scala.swing.Table.  The code is commented out.