# Using TableRowSorter with scala.swing.Table

Tags: scala, swing, jtable

I'm working on simple UI that has a scala.swing.Table component.  I'd like to sort the table rows using java.swing.table.TableRowSorter.  The Table class doesn't provide any API for using a row sorter so I tried setting it directly on the peer

```
val table = new Table(height, width) {
  import javax.swing.table._
  rowHeight = 25
  autoResizeMode = Table.AutoResizeMode.NextColumn
  showGrid = true
  gridColor = new java.awt.Color(150, 150, 150)
  model = myModel

  peer.setRowSorter(new TableRowSorter(model))
}
```

Now when I click on the column headings I get the little up/down arrows but the table contents don't update with the new sort order.  If there's a row selected when I click on the column heading the selection moves to the row where the selected should be in based on the sort order.  I've added custom comparators that they get called as expected so the sorting is really happening but the table isn't being updated.

Am I missing something to get the table to update?  Is it legitimate to access the underlying JTable peer object?

Comment: I had a similar question, look: [sortable-columns-in-scala-swing-table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911759/sortable-columns-in-scala-swing-table)

Comment: Peter, with all the searching I've been doing I wonder how I missed your question?  It looks like your example shows that a simple Component wrapping a JTable supports sorting but the Table class doesn't.  That must mean the problem has something to do with all the other stuff that's in Table.  That's a good clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question.

The scala.swing.Table class doesn't support the row sorting features added in Java 6.  See the Table.scala source file at line 277:

```
def apply(row: Int, column: Int): Any = model.getValueAt(row, viewToModelColumn(column))

// TODO: this is Java 6 stuff
// def apply(row: Int, column: Int): Any = model.getValueAt(viewToModelRow(row), viewToModelColumn(column))
//def viewToModelRow(idx: Int) = peer.convertRowIndexToModel(idx)
//def modelToViewRow(idx: Int) = peer.convertRowIndexToView(idx)
```

I moved the scala.swing files into a different package and built it into my project, then uncommented out the Java 6 stuff and commented out the old apply() method and now table sorting works.

Here's [a link](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4823) to the bug report on this.  The Java 6 code was added back in August and then removed until the Scala library build switches to Java 6.